# Python Unicode issues on sql server database result set

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to retrieve the database results to a webpage using Python 2.7(flask) but stuck with the unicode issues. Below is the code I'm using

```
def formval():
    # --connection syntax here--
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if request.method == 'POST':
    x = request.form['weekno']
    cursor.execute("SELECT Document FROM Backlog where custno=?",x)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('home.html',weekno=result)
```

home.html

```
{% for docno in weekno %}
  <p>{{ docno }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Output : This gives me the output as below

```
 u'sp234780'
 u'sd257679'
---------
---------
```

But when I use `return render_template('home.html',weekno=result[0])` I'm getting the output as just sp234780 but only the first row not the entire results.

I've gone through all the posts related to encoding and tried to use encode('utf-8'), sys.setdefaultsetting(utf-8) etc but no luck

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

The query returns a tuple of tuples. You iterate through the tuple of rows, but each row is itself a tuple, containing a single element. You need to access the element itself.

```
{% for docno in weekno %}
   <p>{{ docno[0] }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one line after the line

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Add this:

```
result = [str(res) for res in result]
```